# How to send an http session cookie using autobench

Tags: http, benchmarking, load-testing, httperf

How do you set a session cookie in autobench so you can benchmark URLs that require session authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked everywhere for this.  Found it [here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/04/):

In your .autobench.conf file, add this line:

```
## Add a session cookie
# NOTE: You must put the '\n' at the end of the cookie string or it will timeout.
httperf_add-header = "Cookie: cookie_name_here=asdf_cookie_string_here_\n"
```

Note that this is different from using httperf's '--session-cookie' and '--wsess=N1,N2,X' params.  They are not required to use a cookie in the header when doing the above.